# Make TextField error true depending on user input in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm a complete beginner to react and javascript and I've managed to make it this far but have run into a problem. I'm unsure how to manipulate Material UI TextField error depending on what the user types in. For example, if the user types in anything that is not number or a number less than zero, I want my TextField error to equal true.

```
          <TextField
                  label="Income"
                  id="income"
                  className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)}
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>,
                  }}
                  variant="outlined"
          />
```

As of right now when the user hits a submit button an exterior function grabs each element by its id and error checks it.

Comment: To make this an easier process, you should read about [controlled inputs in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). This will make it easier to manage the input's values and set other state flags based on those values.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my code to model material-ui's original layout. I added a value, onChange, and error to each of my TextFields like so:

```
<TextField
  label="Income"
  id="income"
  className={clsx(classes.margin, classes.textField)}
  InputProps={{
    startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>,
  }}
  variant="outlined"

  value={values.income}
  onChange={handleChange('income')}
  error={values.income_error}
/>
```

And set these values to a default value:

```
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    income: '',
    income_error: false
   })
```

Then, in my onChange function I checked every desired prop:

```
  const handleChange = prop => event => {
    var error_id, error_val = false, user_input = event.target.value
    error_id = prop + '_error'
    // If statements will highlight red if user types in undesired information
    if (prop === 'purchase_price' || prop === 'down_payment' || prop ===    'interest_rate'
        || prop === 'loan_duration' || prop === 'yearly_payments' || prop === 'income') {
      if ((parseFloat(user_input) < 0 || isNaN(parseFloat(user_input))) && user_input !== '') {
        error_val = true
      }
    }
    setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value, [error_id]: error_val});
  };
```